# SwiftUI Index Out of Range Crash When Clearing Array

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios15

On iOS 15, using SwiftUI, if I set a `@Published var` to a new instance of an object, which has array properties, any views using `ForEach(item) { $item ....` (where `item` conforms to `Identifiable` and `item` is an array `var`) crashes with `SwiftUI.swift: line 635 Index Out of Range` when the new instance is set, i.e. the array items are removed. The same occurs if I just set `self.object.item = []`

lets say I have the following setup:

```
class ExampleClass: ObservableObject {

    static let shared: ExampleClass = ExampleClass()

    @Published var exampleItem: CustomStructure = CustomStructure(param_1: "", param_2: "")

    private init() {
    }

    func doSomethingFirst(completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>)->Void) {
        debugPrint("Did something")
        completion(.success(Void))
    }

    func clearExampleItem() {
        self.doSomethingFirst { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.exampleItem = CustomStructure(param_1: "", param_2: "") // Reset exampleItem clearing all arrays
            }
        }
    }

    struct CustomStructure {
        var customArray: [CustomItem] = []

        init() {
            self.customArray = []
            let customArray: [CustomItem] = []
            for index in 0..<100 {
                let newCustomItem = CustomItem(index: index)
                customArray.append(newCustomItem)
            }
            self.customArray = customArray
        }

        struct CustomItem: Identifiable {
            var id: Int {
                self.index
            }
            var index: Int
            var moreItems: [MoreItem] = [MoreItem(index: 1), MoreItem(index: 2)]
        }
        struct MoreItem: Identifiable {
            var id: Int {
                self.index
            }
            var index: Int
        }
    }
}
```

And in a SwiftUIView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct exampleView: View {

    @StateObject var exampleClass: ExampleClass = ExampleClass.shared

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.$exampleClass.exampleItem.customArray) { $customItem in
                ExampleSubView(exampleClass: self.exampleClass, customItem: $customItem)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleSubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var exampleClass: ExampleClass
    @Binding var customItem: ExampleClass.CustomItem

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(self.customItem.moreItems) { moreItem in
                Button(action: {
                    self.exampleClass.clearExampleItem()
                }) {
                    Text("\(moreItem.index)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once ExampleClass.clearExampleItem() is called, I get the Index Out of Range crash from SwiftUI. This doesn't seem to happen on iOS 16.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a working [mre]? In your current example, you never add anything to `customArray`

Comment: show also where you call your `ExampleClass.clearExampleItem()`, which I suspect should be `ExampleClass.shared.clearExampleItem()` or `exampleClass.clearExampleItem()`

Comment: Updated with example

Answer (score 0):

Its working fie like this:

```
import SwiftUI

            class ExampleClass: ObservableObject {
                
                static let shared: ExampleClass = ExampleClass()
                
                @Published var exampleItem: CustomStructure = CustomStructure()
                
                private init() {
                }
                
                func clearExampleItem() {
                    self.exampleItem.customArray = []
                }
                
                func reload() {
                    self.exampleItem = CustomStructure()
                }
                
                struct CustomStructure {
                    var customArray: [CustomItem] = []
                    
                    init() {
                        var customArray: [CustomItem] = []
                        for index in 0..<100 {
                            let newCustomItem = CustomItem(index: index)
                            customArray.append(newCustomItem)
                        }
                        self.customArray = customArray
                    }
                    
                    struct CustomItem: Identifiable {
                        var id: Int {
                            self.index
                        }
                        var index: Int
                    }
                }
            }

            struct emptyArrayView: View {
                
                @StateObject var exampleClass: ExampleClass = ExampleClass.shared
                
                var body: some View {
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Button("Clear") {
                                    exampleClass.clearExampleItem()
                                }
                                
                                Button("Reload") {
                                    exampleClass.reload()
                                }
                            }
                            
                            ForEach(self.$exampleClass.exampleItem.customArray) { $customItem in
                                Text("\(customItem.id)")
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Is this using iOS 15.5 simulator?
Could it be related to the fact I'm using a closure first, then dispatching the array clear to to the main thread? (Updated example with closure)
Maybe that I have other arrays nested in the ``CustomItem`` structure?